# `objdump` MIPS64 Instruction Encoding—Nonexistent Instruction?

Tags: instructions, objdump, mips64

I have a MIPS64 binary (`readelf` tells me it's release 2), and using a corresponding `objdump` I can see that the first instruction of `__start` is:

```
1200009a0:  03e00025    move    zero,ra
```

I do not understand this.  Looking at [the ISA](https://www.mips.com/?do-download=the-mips64-instruction-set-v5-04)<sup>[note]</sup>, the opcode (first six bits) is `000000₂`, corresponding to the "special" block with function `100101₂` (last six bits): the `or` instruction (ref. pg. 413).  In any case, we see that `move` is not an instruction anyway (ref. §3.2).

However, I notice that some other instructions present in the file exist and are encoded correctly.

**What's going on?  Is this an error in `objdump` or something?  How do I resolve it?**

---

<sub><sup>[note]</sup>Apparently MIPS64 comes in six revisions.  Revisions 1–5 are mostly compatible, while release 6 changes many things.  I wasn't able to find a release 2 specification, so I linked revision 5.  `move` doesn't occur at least in releases 1, 5, or 6, which is all the specifications I could find.</sub>